# Moodle: CSV bulk download of other fields in user profile not showing data

Tags: moodle

Sample Outcome:
[image]

I'm wondering is it possible to show  Gender as Male rather than 2.
It only shows up the number for the answer when uses multi select answers like dropdown etc.

I hope somebody can point me the right direction, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is an old version of Moodle?

You could use something like this instead to replace the numbers with values:

```
SELECT u.id,
        u.username,
        /* any other user fields you need */
        d.user_profile_Gender,
        d.user_profile_AgeGroup,
        d.user_profile_JobTitle,
        d.user_profile_Department
FROM mdl_user u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT d.userid,
    MAX(CASE
            WHEN f.shortname = 'Gender' AND d.data = '1' THEN 'Male'
            WHEN f.shortname = 'Gender' AND d.data = '2' THEN 'Female'
            ELSE null
        END) AS user_profile_Gender,
    MAX(CASE
            WHEN f.shortname = 'AgeGroup' AND d.data = '1' THEN 'xxx'
            WHEN f.shortname = 'AgeGroup' AND d.data = '2' THEN 'yyy'
            ELSE null
        END) AS user_profile_AgeGroup,
    MAX(CASE WHEN f.shortname = 'JobTitle' THEN d.data ELSE null END) AS user_profile_JobTitle,
    MAX(CASE WHEN f.shortname = 'Department' THEN d.data ELSE null END) AS user_profile_Department
    FROM mdl_user_info_data d
    JOIN mdl_user_info_field f ON f.id = d.fieldid
        AND f.shortname IN ('Gender', 'AgeGroup', 'JobTitle', 'Department')
    GROUP BY d.userid
) d ON d.userid = u.id
```